# BeautifulSoup/lxml - Extract href, and converting line breaks to to csv columns?

Tags: beautifulsoup, lxml, extract, export-to-csv

I have a large number of this page saved locally and am working to extract the content and put in a CSV. I have two questions and over two full days I've tried so many solutions it would be difficult to list them here.

Here's the page hosted online for reference: [source page](http://www.abc.ca.gov/datport/SubDlyIssRep.asp)
and code:

```
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/my/path/to/local/files/filename.html"), "lxml")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={ "class" : "report_column"})

headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]

rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
     rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])

url = []

with open('output_file.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
     writer.writerow(["","License Num","Status","Type/ Dup.","Expir. Date","Primary Owner and Premises Addr.","Mailing Address","Action","Conditions","Escrow","District Code","Geo Code"])
     writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

The first question is I need to associate each row of the csv with the date which is shown at the page top, but also available in the href of all the  cols headers. How would I extract that href and either join or somehow add an independent column in the csv?

The second question is, when getting cols with multiple line breaks (like Primary Owner and Mailing Address cols) I'm getting cell content that is one long string. Could you give me any tips on how I could delineate the line breaks with pipes or, ideally put them in unique cols eg Owner1, Owner2, Owner3, Owner4, one for each (up to 4) lines in the cell.

Thanks for any help!

Desired Output:

Right now I'm getting this in the Primary Owner col:
DBA:MECCA DELICATESSEN RAWLINGS, LINDA MAE 215 RESERVATION RDMARINA, CA  93933

And, ideally I could get four cols, one for each row (delineated by a "BR" in table):

col0  July 12, 2017 (date from page header)
col6  DBA:MECCA DELICATESSEN RAWLINGS
col7  LINDA MAE
col8  215 RESERVATION RD
col9  MARINA, CA  93933

Comment: Can you add a sample of what you expect as output?

Comment: I edited question at bottom...

Comment: Any insight or direction would be great.